# Modifying scraper code for multiple URLs

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to download all the images on several pages on the same site. I have some code that grabs all the images from a single page, but can't figure an easy way to make it repeat the process for several URLs.

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

site = 'SiteNameHere'

response = requests.get(site)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
img_tags = soup.find_all('img')

urls = [img['src'] for img in img_tags]

for url in urls:
    filename = re.search(r'/([\w_-]+[.](jpg|gif|png))$', url)
    with open(filename.group(1), 'wb') as f:
        if 'http' not in url:
            url = '{}{}'.format(site, url)
        response = requests.get(url)
        f.write(response.content)
```

Comment: Put all the code except the imports in a function and call it with the URLs as arguments.

Comment: `for site in [ yoursite1, yoursite2, yoursite3]:` do what you do for one site?

Comment: Voting to close- this is such a trivial thing to do and there are tons on pyhton scape threads all over SO how to do so. Downvote for : No Research, No Attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to add/change each url request inside the for loop. Look the example below (using the requests module and lxml):

```
import lxml.html
import requests

#List of CSID numbers
ListOfNumbers = ['12','132','455']

for CSID in CSIDList:   

     UrlCompleted = ('http://www.chemspider.com/ChemicalStructure.%s.html?rid' %CSID)
     ChemSpiderPage = requests.get(UrlCompleted)
     html = lxml.html.fromstring(ChemSpiderPage.content)
     #Xpath describing the location of the string (see "text()" at the end)
     MolecularWeight = html.xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentSection_ContentPlaceHolder1_RecordViewDetails_rptDetailsView_ctl00_structureHead"]/ul[1]/li[2]/text()')

          try:
               print (CSID, MolecularWeight)
               print (MolecularWeight)   
          except:
               print 'ERROR'
```